# java android return method within listener?

Tags: java, android

I am kind of new in Java Android, and Im facing this problem and i don't know what it's called, here is my code:

```
public boolean msgBox(String title, String text) {
    boolean bReturn = false;
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    adb.setCancelable(false);
    adb.setTitle(title);
    adb.setMessage(text);
    adb.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //this suppose tell msgBox return true
        }
    });

    adb.setNegativeButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //this suppose tell msgBox return false
        }
    });

    adb.show();

    return bReturn;
}
```

Now how do I tell msgBox to return true / false when user clicked positive / negative button? thanks before

Comment: If one value is clicked, set a boolean variable, and then just return that variable.

Comment: @Zizouz212 That way, method would return, before anything is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, because the method will end after the Dialog is opened. The Dialog will continue to be open after the method is finished.

In order to return information back to your msgBox caller, you will need to provide a callback function.

You can create an interface, pass that into msgBox, and call it in your Dialog button.

```
public interface OnDialogButtonClickedCallback {
    public void onDialogButtonClicked(boolean wasPositive);
}
```

Pass it in like this:

```
public boolean msgBox(String title, String text, final OnDialogButtonClickedCallback callback)
```

Use it in the button like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    if(callback != null) {
        callback.onDialogButtonClicked(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        if(which == 1) {
           bReturn = true or false;//yes or no
        }
        //this suppose tell msgBox return false
    }
```

In the function above you determine which button was clicked by variable int which (f.e.: Yes is first, No is second).

bReturn should be global.

Since you are doing separate listeners for each button, you don't even have to distinguish, since those are separate listeners.